# Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ThemeProvider>

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-elements

`ThemeProvider` from `react-native-elements` in not allowing childrens.

Here is the code :

```
const Root = () => {
  const {theme, isNewUser} = Settings.useContainer();
  const darkMode = useMemo(() => theme === 'dark', [theme]);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme} useDark={darkMode}>
      {isNewUser ? <OnboardingStack /> : <BottomTab />}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

ThemeProvider is having red underline, on hover it is saying

```
Type '{ children: Element; theme: RCTheme; useDark: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ThemeProvider> & Pick<Readonly<ThemeProviderProps>, never> & InexactPartial<...> & InexactPartial<...>'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ThemeProvider> & Pick<Readonly<ThemeProviderProps>, never> & InexactPartial<...> & InexactPartial<...>'.ts(2322)
```

[image]

Comment: Since React 18 you need to add children to the props explicitly. I guessing it's the same for React Native. How's `ThemeProvider` defined?

Comment: @Anton and how to add children to props, did you mean add children props in types in file `node_modules/react-native-elements/dist/config/ThemeProvider.d.ts`

Answer (score 0):

```
type ExistingThemeProviderProps = ComponentProps<typeof ThemeProvider> & {children: ReactNode};
export const ThemeProviderExtended = (props: ExistingThemeProviderProps) => <ThemeProvider {...props}/>
```

This fixed the issue for me, till react-native-elements team releases type fix.